# NodeJS reading and producing SAS files: xport and sas7bdat

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sas

I have been looking around for a way to digest and export SAS files using NodeJS. I guess it can be done by means of:

1. C++ extension to NodeJS
2. Some sort of JavaScript framework

I couldn't find anything ready made on the Internet. I haven't tried to cook one up myself. I am not considering other options such as to get SAS to export CSVs. I assume that SAS is not available to NodeJS.

Does anyone know of any ready made way of making NodeJS to work with xport and sas7bdat files?

Regards,
Vasilij

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made this for sas7bdat files: https://github.com/dumbmatter/sas7bdat-js

It's a pure JS module for reading sas7bdat files in NodeJS. Install with:

```
npm install sas7bdat
```

Then load the module:

```
const SAS7BDAT = require('sas7bdat');
```

`SAS7BDAT.createReadStream` returns a stream that emits individual rows, one at a time:

```
const stream = SAS7BDAT.createReadStream('test.sas7bdat');
stream.on('data', row => console.log(row));
stream.on('end', () => console.log('Done!'));
stream.on('error', err => console.log(err));
```

`SAS7BDAT.parse` returns a promise that resolves to an array containing all the rows:

```
SAS7BDAT.parse('test.sas7bdat')
    .then(rows => console.log(rows))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: hello, looks like it has and error on WIndows 10npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fs-ext@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fs-ext@2.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Sorry I don't have Windows, but a PR is welcome if you figure out what the problem is :)